# Python: Is there a faster way to filter on dataframe in a for loop

Tags: python, performance, cplex, docplex

I have a for loop over a tuple in python which is index for one dataframe. All the values under the index are then summed over.

Example:

```
t3 = time()
for row in list_of_index:
    a=[]
    if row[-1]!='end':
        a=df1.loc[row[:7]].to_numpy()
    b=df2.loc[row[:6]].to_numpy()
    print(solver.add_constraint(solver.sum(dvSupportedOuts[row[0], row[6],row[1], 
 row2[0],row[2],row2[1],row2[2],row[3],row[4] ,row2[3],row[5],row2[4],row2[5],row2[6] ,row2[7],row2[8]] 
                                     for row2 in np.reshape(a, (-1, 11))) 
        ==                solver.sum(dvSupportedOuts[row[0], row2[0], row[1], 
                                     row[2], row2[1],row[3],row[4],row2[2],row2[3],row[5],row2[4],row2[5],row2[6],row2[7],row2[8],row2[9]] 
                                     for row2 in np.reshape(b, (-1, 12)))#size of step_sequence
        + dvMBDown[row[0], row[6], row[1], row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]]
        - dvMBUp[row[0], row[6], row[1], row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]]))
print(area_name+" mb:", round((time()-t3), 1), "s")
```

This is the constraint I am making and it returns more than 100k constraints. It takes 40 mins to run this code while threading. The filter helps to return less data for loop running in solver.sum().
Is there a faster way to filter values inside the for loop?
(This is being done for docplex constraint creation)
Thanks

Comment: [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) takes a list. [`numpy.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) takes an `axis` argument. Use this to get a 2D array and sum along the columns. Much faster than iterating over columns

Comment: Also, your tags indicate that you may be using `docplex`. `docplex` has a function `Model.sum` which is much faster than Python's builtin `sum`. As usual, you should have provided a fully working minimal example so that we can what exactly you are doing and in which context.

Comment: Always use `Model.sum`  to compute sum of variables. Python `sum` is too slow. This method accepts lists, generators, pandas Series, and numpy arrays

Comment: I am using Model.sum() unfortunately its still slow.

Comment: Does it help to add all constraints in one shot? I.e., use `add_constraints()` instead of multiple calls to `add_constraint()`. Also, are you sure that the time is spent in `add_constraint()` or in `sum()`? I.e., are you sure that the time is spent in `docplex`? Maybe the time is burnt in the various calls to `to_numpy()` or `reshape()`?

Comment: I was able to make it 18x faster, the main time was spent on the filter (.loc()). First I updated my index from multi- Index to single index which is concatenate of all the index columns. This lead to 3x speed improvement. Then I changed my dataframe to dictionary and it lead to total speed up of 15x. Now I am able to create the model constraint in 3 min instead of 45 mins.Usually I have not seen significant improvement of speed using add_constrains() but sometimes it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it 18x faster, the main time was spent on the filter (.loc()). First I updated my index from multi- Index to single index which is concatenate of all the index columns. This lead to 3x speed improvement. Then I changed my dataframe to dictionary and it lead to total speed up of 15x. Now I am able to create the model constraint in 3 min instead of 45 mins. Moreover I am already threading (parallel processing) this over 1 of the index. Usually I have not seen significant improvement of speed using add_constrains() but sometimes it helps.
50k constraints form data with 600k rows in 3 mins
If required I can share the logic

Comment: If you are summing only variables,  `Model.sum_vars` might improve performance.